# Spacing after custom symbol varies

Tags: spacing, symbols

**Situation:** I defined a box with a line in it via

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\lbox}{\text{%
  \tikz[baseline=-.6ex, rounded corners=.01ex]
    {\draw (-.6ex,-.6ex) rectangle (.6ex,.6ex);
     \draw (0,-.6ex) -- (0,.6ex);}}\kern-.2ex}
```

The symbol is contained in a `\text`-box so that it scales appropriately to sub- and superscripts. (I do not like the solution using `\scalebox` for scaling because it takes too long in large files. I could of course use `\mathchoice`, but that's a bit of extra work again.) I put a `\kern-.2ex` at the end so that it has the right distance to the next symbol: as is, the distance between the box and the phi `$\lbox\phi$` is the same as in `$\boxempty\phi$`.

**Problem:** When `lbox` is followed by something in brackets, like `$\lbox(\phi \wedge \psi)$`, the spacing is incorrect: there is too little space between the box and the bracket. This is not the case when using `$\boxempty(\phi \wedge \psi)$`.
[image]

**Question:** How do I fix this? How can I ensure constant spacing after my `lbox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that `\boxempty` is from `stmaryrd`. This symbol is defined as a binary operation symbol, so it behaves like `+` and `-`.

In the case of `$-1$`, no space is added between the symbols, but you would have spaces on either side of `-` in $a-b$. The same happens to `\boxempty`.

You're instead defining $\lbox$ as a math operator, which means that in $\lbox\varphi$ a thin space will be inserted between the symbols, but no such space is inserted in case you do $\lbox($ (the same behavior as for `\sin`).

So the comparison between `\lbox` and `\boxempty` is not correct: they're animals with different *genera*, not just *species*.

If you want to use `\lbox` in the same way as `\nabla`, then it should be an ordinary operator, because this is the typesetting tradition. And it should have some sidebearings (see the comparison between the bounding boxes in the picture).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz,stmaryrd}

\newcommand{\lbox}{%
  \mspace{1.5mu}%
  \text{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-.6ex, rounded corners=.01ex]
      \draw (-.6ex,-.6ex) rectangle (.6ex,.6ex);
      \draw (0,-.6ex) -- (0,.6ex);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
  \mspace{1.5mu}%
}

\begin{document}

\begingroup % compare the bounding boxes
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\fcolorbox{red}{white}{$\lbox$}

\fcolorbox{red}{white}{$\boxempty$}
\endgroup

$\mathord{\boxempty}\varphi$

$\lbox\varphi$

$\lbox(\varphi)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's very interesting! Would you say it's better to use \mspace compared to \hspace or \kern?

Comment: @MathStudent020 `\mspace` will automatically change size in sub/superscripts